# How to use $lookup $let variables in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup

Trying to do a [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) and use one of the variables but using $expr is confusing.

I'm pretty sure the let part is right, but it says to use it in the pipeline you need an $expr, but I don't understand where or what information to give it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    {"$lookup": {
        "from": "likes",
        "let": {'content': "$_id"},
        "pipeline": [{'$match': { '$expr':  
            {user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id), content: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("$$content")}
           }}],
        "as": "liked"
    }},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only convert `req.user._id` using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` as it becomes a constant value for Aggregation Framework. To convert a variable `$$content` you have to use [$toObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) operator.

```
{"$lookup": {
    "from": "likes",
    "let": {'content': "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
        {'$match': { $expr: { $and: [ 
            { $eq: [ "$user", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id) ] },
            { $eq: [ "$content", { $toObjectId: "$$content" } ] },
        ] } } }
    ],
    "as": "liked"
}},
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution seems to work. Seems I also missed that $expr can only have one argument so you have to use $and to evaluate things... pretty confusing and verbose...